# Unable to get record Name, only get recordId to display in Flow Builder

Tags: visual-workflow, new, spring19

I'm checking out the new Flow Builder in the Spring '19 release, and I'm running into an issue with what I would *think* to be a simple task; retrieving the name/text from a field on the current record, and displaying that on the screen.

I've got it pulling the recordId for the record the user is on when launching the flow. It is also correctly pulling the recordId for the **account** said record is related to. I have it display that text, which is supposed to be an actual account name, on the screen element, but it just displays the recordId of said account name.

I would assume I'm needing to somehow convert that ID to a normal text/string so the name appears, but I'm not sure what exactly to do.

Answer (score 2):

The recordId variable is just the id of the record. You will need to use Get Records to query the actual account record, and pull the account name from that.

1. In the Toolbox, under Manager, create a new resource of type Variable. The API Name should be recordId, data type Text, and mark it Available for Input.
2. There are a couple of ways to store information about the account. If you just want a field or two, you can create variables for those (for example, create a variable of type Text for the name). If you want a lot of fields, you could create a Record variable. For this example, I'll assume a text variable called AccountName.
3. Add a [Get Records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_data_get.htm) element to your canvas. Object type is Account; filter on Id = {!recordId}; store field values in separate variables, and store the account Name field in your AccountName variable (see screenshot below).

[image]

Drag the connector from the Start node to your Get Records node, and then from the Get Records node to your screen. You can now use the AccountName variable to display the name in your screen.